# Is it intensive to get a model instance's property in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to Django and have the following model:

```
Person:
- height
- weight
- name
```

In one of my functions, I get `person.height` 5 times. Would it be better (from a computation perspective) to just store `height = person.height` and reference that?

Comment: **No**, it is only fetched *once* from the database with the entire model, and then fetching it will not take significant effort. You can store it in a local variable, but that will have not *that* much impact.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem but wouldn't it give the code better radability if you just declared a variable and stored the value in it? It wouldnt affect fetching the data either

Comment: @SLDem: that is more opinion-based. Defining a local variable can increase readability, but it can also introduce confusion if there are multiple objects that havr a `.height`.  I think `person.height` is more clear than `height`, since then it is clear it is the `height` of that person, not of the `table` somewhere else. Of course one wants to avoid a *train wreck antipattern*, so if there are two or more attributes involved, it often pays of to use a temporary variable to store some item.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think in this perticular case there is only one object with height attribute so it would probably make more sense to declare a variable and store it there, maybe call it person_height or something like that

Comment: @SLDem: well `person_height` or `person.height` does not changes much in terms of readability (since it basically replaces *syntically* a `.` for a `_`, yes semantically it is different). Defining a lot of local variables often only introduces more code, and will often also make it harder since the IDE will propose more variables and picking the "right one" is harder.

Comment: Yes, in that case we would just call it `height` and use that instead